# Question on a remark in Speh's paper

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis

I am reading Birgit Speh's paper entitled "Unitary representations of Gl(n,R) with nontrivial (g,K)-cohomology" in Invent. Math. 71 (1983), no. 3, 443–465. In Remark 1.2.2.(b), it says that "It was pointed out to me by J. Dixmier that the representations $I(k)$ coincide with those mentioned
in [5]." Here [5] is the paper by Gelfand and Graev entitled "Unitary representations of the real unimodular group" in Translations American Math. Soc. (2) 2, 147-206 (1956).

My question is how to understand this remark? In particular, how to show that Gelfand-Graev's construction is isomorphic to the Speh representations? For the convenience of the reader, I also copy the construction of Gelfand-Graev in [5] as follows.

"For simplicity we shall consider the group $G$ of real fourth-order matrices. It turns out that the manifold $Z$ of complex matrices, on which the group $G$ acts, falls into two manifolds $Z^+$ and $Z^-$ which are transitive with respect to $G$ and which have the same dimensionality as $Z$ itself, together with a manifold of lower dimensionality which borders on them. Our representations are realised in fact in the space of functions, defined on one of the manifolds $Z^+$ and $Z^-$.

With a suitable choice of parameters the manifolds $Z^+$ and $Z^-$ may be regarded as manifolds of pairs $(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})$ o f points of the three-dimensional space $\mathcal B$, $z^{\prime}(z^{\prime}_1, z^{\prime}_2, z^{\prime}_3)$ and $z^{\prime\prime}(z^{\prime\prime}_1,z^{\prime\prime}_2,z^{\prime\prime}_3)$, whose coordinates satisfy the inequality
\begin{equation}
\Delta(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})=\begin{vmatrix}
z^{\prime}_1&z^{\prime}_2&z^{\prime}_3&1\\
z^{\prime\prime}_1&z^{\prime\prime}_2&z^{\prime\prime}_3&1\\
\bar z^{\prime}_1&\bar z^{\prime}_2&\bar z^{\prime}_3&1\\
\bar z^{\prime\prime}_1&\bar z^{\prime\prime}_2&\bar z^{\prime\prime}_3&1\\
\end{vmatrix}>0.
\end{equation}
or th e inequalit $\Delta(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})<0$, respectively.

The action of the group $G$ in the three-dimensional space $\mathcal B$ is in effect that a matrix $g=(g_{pq})$ transforms the point $z(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ of this space into a point $z\bar g:=(\hat z_1,\hat z_2,\hat z_3)$ with the coordinates
\begin{equation}
\hat z_i=\frac{z_1g_{1i}+z_2g_{2i}+z_3g_{3i}+g_{4i}}{z_1g_{14}+z_2g_{24}+z_3g_{34}+g_{44}},\,i=1,2,3.
\end{equation}

A representation of the series under consideration is constructed in the space of functions $f(z^{\prime}, z^{\prime\prime})$ of the six complex variables $z^{\prime}_i$ and $z^{\prime\prime}_j$ $(i, j=l,2,3)$, which are defined over one of the above manifolds. We require that these functions should be analytic in all the variables  $z^{\prime}_i$ and $z^{\prime\prime}_j$ on the manifold in question. We require furthermore that for these functions and for fixed positive integral $m$ there should converge the integral
\begin{equation}
\int|f(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})|^2|\Delta(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})|^{m-4}dz_1^{\prime}dz_2^{\prime}dz_3^{\prime}dz_1^{\prime\prime}dz_2^{\prime\prime}dz_3^{\prime\prime}.
\end{equation}
(Here $dz$ denotes the product $dxdy$, if $z=x+iy$.)
The representation is given by a positive integer $m$ and consists in that to every fourth-order matrix $g=(g_{pq})$ there corresponds a mapping which takes thebfunction $f(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})$ into the function
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,T_gf(z^{\prime},z^{\prime\prime})=\\
&f(z^{\prime}\bar g,z^{\prime\prime}\bar g)[(z^{\prime}_1g_{14}+z^{\prime}_2g_{24}+z^{\prime}_3g_{34}+g_{44})(z^{\prime\prime}_1g_{14}+z^{\prime\prime}_2g_{24}+z^{\prime\prime}_3g_{34}+g_{44})]^{-m}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}"